# Error in Validating Login Form details in PHP

Tags: php, validation, parameters, array-push

**Following is the code**

```
function addValidation($variable,$validator,$error)
    {
        $validator_obj = new ValidatorObj();
        $validator_obj->variable_name = $variable;
        $validator_obj->validator_string = $validator;
        $validator_obj->error_string = $error;
        array_push($this->validator_array,$validator_obj);
    }
```

**Following is the error found: Please tell me what to do?**

```
[02-Jun-2018 19:38:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/gurudev/public_html/login/include/formvalidator.php on line 90
[02-Jun-2018 19:38:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/gurudev/public_html/login/include/formvalidator.php on line 90
[02-Jun-2018 19:38:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/gurudev/public_html/login/include/formvalidator.php on line 90
[02-Jun-2018 19:38:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/gurudev/public_html/login/include/formvalidator.php on line 90
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't see what your `ValidatorObj()` object constructs.

But as the error suggests your `$this->validator_array` gives null, because it's not set, while at least `$this->validator_array = array();` is expected (either in your function or in the object construct).

Plus `$this->validator_array` works only within the class itself, so I am not really sure where you really try to "save" your `$validator_obj` data.